# I cannot delete anything in my archive folder

Tags: delete

When I try to delete files out of my archive folder I can't move them to the trash and also when I highlight them and go shift-delete that also doesn't work

Comment: What is an "archive folder"? Edit your question to show us the output of `ls -l nameOfThatFolder`.

Answer (score 0):

open the terminal and type

```
sudo -i
```

Enter the required password for your system. then type

```
cd /var/cache/apt/archives/
```

To check the whole list of packages in the archive folder, type

```
ls
```

To remove any package, Type

```
rm package_name.deb
```

Hope it helps.